# CSS speech bubble after tag causing a bug

Tags: jquery, css, speech

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Muc7/)

```
ul{
    height:240px;
    border:1px solid #000;

}
#react-setting{
    background:rgba(255, 253, 200, 1);
    z-index:2;
    display:block;      
    position:absolute;
    width:125px;
    padding:6px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;

}
#react-setting:after{
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width:8px;
    left: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 45deg );
    -moz-transform: rotate( 45deg );
    background:rgba(255, 253, 200, 1);
        box-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
}
```

What I want is a continuous `box-shadow` around both `#react-setting` and its `:after`. Right now it looks like this:

[image: problematic bubble]

As you can see, the `:after` has its own complete `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got decent results using the following for `#react-setting:after` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/2Muc7/3/)):

```
 box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
```

Sample:

[image: sample bubble]